# Simultaneous Diophantine approximation in the non-generic case

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation, computational-number-theory

Suppose we have $n$ irrational numbers $\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \}$. For a generic set of such numbers, we have the well-known theorem that there exist infinitely many  integers $q$ such that

$$ \max\{ \parallel q x_1 \parallel,  \parallel q x_2 \parallel, \ldots, \parallel q x_n \parallel\} <  q^{-1/n}.$$

Here $\parallel \cdot \parallel $ means the distance of the number to the closest integer.

The point is, could this theorem be strengthened if the $n$ numbers are **somehow related**? As an example, what if

$$ \{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \} = \{ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}, \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\}?$$

Comment: I'm not clear if you're using the term *generic* in a technical sense (that is you are saying that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ belong to a dense $G_\delta$ set),  or whether you just mean for an arbitrary $n$-tuple. The fact you quote is a corollary of the pigeonhole principle, so is true for all $n$-tuples.

Comment: By Lindenstrauss' et Al. result towards the Littlewood conjecture, your inequality (in a sharper form) holds for much larger set than plain  "generic" (namely, up to dimension $0$ subset),

Comment: You may be interested in a result by Cassels and SD about numbers from real cubic fields (in retrospect, one of the first instances of the interplay between dynamics and NT) - https://dx.doi.org/10.1098%2Frsta.1955.0010

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  Yes, I mean arbitrary actually.

Comment: I gave an apparently unsatisfying answer to this same question on Math StackExchange.  See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186331/simultaneous-diophantine-approximation-in-the-non-generic-case/2193881#2193881